# HTML - How to handle arabic text inversion without duplicating code nor JS

Tags: html, css, text, arabic

I want to achieve the following :

If not Arabic

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Price                            500 |
+---------------------------------------
```

If arabic

```
+--------------------------------------+
| 500                            Price |
+---------------------------------------
```

Currently "500" is in a div and "Price" is in a div.

- If not Arabic, I create the "Price" div first (align left) and then the "500" div (align right).
- If Arabic, I create the "500" div first (align left) and then the "Price" div (align right).

In conclusion, I either have to duplicate the code (to handle the fact that each div can be on the left or on the right) or to create it dynamically with JS (meh). I want a simpler solution because if I have a lot more properties than just "Price", the code will be fatuously complicated.

Comment: [This](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/) might help

Comment: I did not mention it because this attribute seems to only align the text on the left or on the right. I need something that can switch words from left to right or right to left. Like a mirror function.

Comment: Don't swap the two divs around physically. Instead, apply LTR or RTL properties/attributes to the container of the two divs.

Comment: Oh yeah it works (see https://jsfiddle.net/72hnbfxt/1/). Thank you I will try to use that.

Comment: If like in my example you use "float" to align the text on the right or on the left, you need to set the correct value (a variable) into the "float" attribute depending on the value of "direction" (or any other that let you know if you are in arabic or not). See example : https://jsfiddle.net/72hnbfxt/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change direction in style to rtl for Arabic.
See this example:

```
 <table style="direction: ltr">
      <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>500</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```